# Defining setters and getters in Nuxt / Vuex store for API access

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I am currently creating a Nuxt app, which uses an API-backend to get it's data from. Since I don't know what data is needed when the page loads, I would like to stay clear of fetching on `mounted()` or explicitly fetching when I need the resource and then also accessing it but instead define getters and setters in the Nuxt/Vuex store to return the data if present or fetch if missing.
Suppose I have the following data structure(s):
(projects.json)

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "randomdata": "abc",
    "client": 1
  }
]
```

(clients.json)

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Max"
  }
]
```

My page would look something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div
      v-for="project in projects">
      <p>
        {{project.randomdata}}
      </p>
      <v-checkbox
        v-bind="showClient">
        Show client
      </v-checkbox>
      <p
        v-if="showClient">
        {{ clients.find(c => c.id === project.client) }}
      </p>
    </div>
</template>
```

I tried multiple places to register the getters without success:

- registering getters and setters directly in `computed` ==> throws "Cannot read property '$store' of undefined", I guess this is undefined

```js
projects: {
  get: () => {this.$store.dispatch('get', {resource: 'projects'}); return this.$store.state.projects}
  set: (value) => this.$store.dispatch('set', {resource: 'projects', value})
}
```

- getters, mutations in store; using `mapState` ==> Didn't get both getters and setters configured on computed property

```js
getters: {
    plants: state => {
        return get(state, 'plants', this.$axios);
    }
},
mutations: {
    plants(state, value) {
        save('plants', state.plants, value);
    },
},
```

- javascript getters / setters in `state` ==> couldn't get axios so I could do the request as intended, also is this reactive?

```js
state: () => ({
    _plants: {},
    get plants() {
        return get(this, 'plants');
    },
    set plants(value) {
        this.plants = save('plants', this._plants, value);
    }
}),
```

All of the above assuming the appropriate methods exist and work as intended.

I assume that an object is returned from the getters, whose properties are filled once the asynchronous request finished.

I would really apprciate if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to properly define these getters and setters.

TL;DR; What is the best way to define getters and setters for API requests using Nuxt/Vuex store?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is writing your state in the correct position.
I have setting folder having index.js file in state folder.

```
store/
-------|index.js
-------|setting/
-----------| index.js
```

- the first `index.js` file just inside store folder is the main state.
- the second `index.js` file inside store/setting folder is the state having setting states.

now, I have state object called `options` in setting state (in `store/setting/index.js`). just like this ...

```
export const state = () => ({
  options: {
    page: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 25
  }
})

export const mutations = {
  setOptions(state, options) {
    state.options = options
  },
}
```

now in your page, you can build the options getter/setter like this ...

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    options: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.setting.options
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('setting/setOptions', value)
      }
    },
  },
}
```

It is working for me and I'm also using it on my projects.
Ask me if it is not clear to you.